# PHP Login authentication

Tags: php, session, if-statement

So I have a script which checks the login details.. I have that working, but I would like to further develop this with more specific information.

There will be 2 errors; Incorrect password / username or Account not activated

I have this code, but I get the following error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE"

```
} else if  ($active=="no"); {
header("Location: ../index.php?NotActived");
exit();
}

 else {
     header("location: ../index.php?Badpass");
     exit();

}
```

I do have an `if` stament at the top of my script which creates the session if the user details ar correct. I'm aware I could do this in ajax/jquery but I'm kinda new to that and for this small project, I'd like to stick to php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
} else if  ($active=="no"); {
```

You need to remove the semicolon:

```
} else if  ($active=="no") {
```

Answer (score 1):

```
} else if  ($active=="no"); {
```

should be

```
} else if ($active=="no") {
```